# What can I do to fix this fatal error?

Tags: swift3, ios10, dropbox-api

I'm completely new to API's, and am following [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/dropbox-api-tutorial/) to implement Dropbox's API into an iPhone app I'm building. The tutorial was written in an earlier version of swift, so my problem could be an issue in translation. I'm pretty far along in the tutorial where it says that I should be able to run the app, but when I do, it crashes with a fatal error.

[image]

Here's the ViewController.swift code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblFiles: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var bbiConnect: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tblFiles.delegate = self
        tblFiles.dataSource = self

        progressBar.isHidden = true

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("handleDidLinkNotification:")), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "didLinkToDropboxAccountNotification"), object: nil)

        func handleDidLinkNotification(notification: NSNotification)
        {
            bbiConnect.title = "Disconnect"
        }

        if DBSession.shared().isLinked() {
            bbiConnect.title = "Disconnect"
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: IBAction method implementation

    @IBAction func connectToDropbox(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if !DBSession.shared().isLinked() {
            DBSession.shared().link(from: self)
        }
        else {
            DBSession.shared().unlinkAll()
            bbiConnect.title = "Connect"
        }

    }


    @IBAction func performAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    }


    @IBAction func reloadFiles(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    }


    // MARK: UITableview method implementation

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }

}
```

And the AppDelegate.swift code

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    @nonobjc func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let appKey = "XXXXX"      // Set your own app key value here.
        let appSecret = "XXXXX"   // Set your own app secret value here.

        let dropboxSession = DBSession(appKey: appKey, appSecret: appSecret, root: kDBRootAppFolder)
        DBSession.setShared(dropboxSession)

        return true
    }

    @nonobjc func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

        if DBSession.shared().handleOpen(url as URL!) {
            if DBSession.shared().isLinked() {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

I'm out of my depth here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check your all 3 outlet is properly connected or not.

Comment: In the future, you should remove the values for your app key and secret from your question. They should be kept private and are not necessary to provide an answer.

Comment: @NiravD How do I do that? I'm basically just copy/pasting the code from the tutorial. Would I just re-drag them over to the ViewController.swift ?

Comment: @Theodore.K The drag the outlet from storyboard to viewcontroller and leave on Outlet declaration to its specific type.